# Squared Acceleration

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, acceleration

For vibration event waves, subjected to sinusoidal impacts, over a fixed mechanic element:

- the integral of the squared velocity can be interpreted as a kinetic energy,
- the integral of the squared displacement can be interpreted as a mechanical potential energy, through an elasticity modulus,

I am asking if the integral of the squared acceleration can be interpreted as any valid physics magnitude -such as a hamiltonian, lagrangian, action, or other similar- which could be related to an energy in some way.

Both of the displacement, the velocity and the acceleration dynamical response can be reprented in a same plot, hence they are actually related by an integral so thats why i am asking for the meaning of the squared acceleration integral in this case.

[image]

Comment: The only example I can think of is the Larmor formula, which says that the radiation power emitted by a charge is proportional to $a^2$. So the integral of $a^2$ gives the total energy lost to radiation.

Comment: I found a very obscure reference to the [Arias Intensity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arias_Intensity) which measures the strength of a seismic wave. But this do not have a mechanical meaning. Or it do?